# jQuery parent or parents to get data-attribute in table th tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that are like a grid with a horizontal list in the top with week numbers within `th` tags and below each week are different values in rows of `tr` and `td` tags.

I'm trying to get the `data-attribute` for the `week` when I click below in one of the `td` tags with the `data-id attribute`. But I can't get it right and wonder what I have done wrong to be able to read this value?

Some of the combinations I have tested:

```
var test = $(this).closest("th").attr("data-week");
var test = $(this).parents().find(".week").attr("data-week");
var test = $(this).parents("th").attr("data-week");
```

The HTML with data-attributes for the table:

```
 <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class=""></th>
                    <th class="week" data-week="15">15</th>
                    <th class="week" data-week="16">16</th>
                    <th class="week" data-week="17">17</th>
                    <th class="week" data-week="18">18</th>
                    <th class="week" data-week="19">19</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Stina (1)</td>
                            <td data-id="40">10</td>
                            <td data-id="12">20</td>
                            <td data-id="13">40</td>
                            <td data-id="14">45</td>
                            <td data-id="15">40</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Linda (2)</td>
                            <td data-id="0">0</td>
                            <td data-id="0">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lasse (3)</td>
                            <td data-id="21">5</td>
                            <td data-id="22">39</td>
                            <td data-id="23">40</td>
                            <td data-id="24">40</td>                       
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sean DiSanti, good one!
Here is a slightly more efficient version, without warping $ in $, by using eq method

```
$('td').on('click', function(e) {
  var index = $(this).index() -1;
  var week = $('.week').eq(index).data('week');
  console.log('week', week);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/strannij/c7z096cd/3/)

Comment: Your code is nice and simple! Is the 'e' really necessary in the click function?

Comment: It's not, It's there in case you need to access event information, or prevent bubbling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can find the **data-week** attribute of the clicked th element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("td").on("click",function(){
         $td=$(this);
         $th = $td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index());
         alert($th.attr("data-week"));
     });    
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/7b146hor/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to find it by index. Get which child number the clicked element has and then look for same number in `.weeks`

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/yixama/edit?html,js,output)

```
$('td').on('click', function(e){
  index = $(this).index();
  week  = $('.weeks').find(":eq("+index+")").attr('data-week');
  console.log(week);
});
```

Comment: your fiidle code works nice, but when I paste your code into my script, week variable is undefined! Very strange!?

Comment: oh you need to add the `.weeks` class. Anyway Byaxy got it better i think.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$('td').on('click', function(e) {
  index = $(this).index();
  week = $($('.week')[index - 1]).data('week');
  console.log('week', week);
});
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/c7z096cd/)